# Как подключить SQLite к CLR Visual studio 2022?

Tags: c++, winforms, sqlite3, c++-cli

Я пытался просто подключить sqlite3.h, но ему требуется sqlite3.c, а в CLR проектах (у меня Windows forms) нельзя компилировать C файлы. Может, его можно компилировать без флага /clr? Как его убрать? Или есть другие способы работы с sqlite в VS22 C++/CLI?